# Why are two functions not identical?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$$f(x)=\ln(x^2)\\
g(x) = 2\ln(x)$$

Why are these two functions not equal?
I can't understand why since:

$$e^{\ln(x^2)}=(e^{\ln(x)})^2\\
x^2 = x^2$$

And the domain is more than zero in both cases.

Comment: $f(x)$ is defined for all non-zero $x$, $g(x)$ is only defined for $x>0$ (assuming you are talking about real variables here).

Comment: @lulu Oh that makes sense, since $x^2$ is always positive. May I ask out of curiosity, what would be the case if $x$ could be a complex number ?

Comment: For complex arguments you would have to take care to define what you meant by the log.  As the function $e^z$ is periodic, there are infinitely many solutions to $e^z=x$ so you have to make sure you are choosing a branch consistently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they have different [natural domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function#Natural_domain).

On the other hand, in $(0,\infty)$, $f(x)=g(x)$.

A similar example:
$$
g(x)=\sqrt{x},\quad f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is they **DO NOT** share a common domain. $f:\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \Bbb R$ since $f$ is defined over negative numbers too. Whereas $g:\Bbb R\setminus(-\infty,0]\to \Bbb R$ and $g$ is not defined on -ve numbers. Now since $f(-1)$ exists and $g(-1)$ does not so they are not equal!